# Upper bound for the smallest integer which makes $nk+1$ prime number

Tags: prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

The Dirichlet theorem of primes in arithmetic progression tells us that for a given  $a$ and $b$  that are coprime there are infinitely  integers $k$ s.t  $ ak+b $ is prime.

Suppose we take $a=n$, $n$ is odd, and $b=1$ .

For each $n$ and $k$ is the smallest one which makes $nk+1$ prime,
what is the best upper bound which we
know for $k$ i.e $ k<C $ where C can be a constant or a function depends on $n$ or $k$?

Comment: Semantics nit-pick: The way your first paragraph is constructed makes it not say what you want it to say. Once you say "there is an integer $k$", all the variables are fixed, and there is only a single integer, and thus at most a single prime, of the form $ak+b$. Instead, you could say something like "for each integer $a,b$ relatively prime, there are infinitely integers $k$ s.t. $ak+b$ is prime." or "[...] there are infinitely many primes of the form $ak+b$ for integral $k$."

Comment: [Linnik's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem) is the result you're looking for.

Comment: @Greg Martin but it gives an upper bound for the least prime in arithmetic progression, not for $k$?

Comment: Just divide the upper bound for the least prime by $n$.